# How to clear all input fields in a specific div with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to do a simple thing: clear the input fields of a group of input field within a div whenever the form loads, or if the user changes a picklist; but I'm having a devil of a time getting the selector to work.

First, here's my onclick and onload triggers:

```
<form name="EditGenotype" action="process_GenotypeMaint.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return false" onload=clear_fetch() >
```

and on the picklists:

```
<SELECT multiple size=6 NAME="marker" onchange=show_marker() onclick=clear_fetch() >
```

Next, here's my HTML input elements in the div I want to clear:

```
  <div class=fetch_results>
      <fieldset>
    <LEGEND><b>Edit Genotype, call 1</b></LEGEND>
      <boldlabel>Allele_1</boldlabel><input id=allele_1_1 name=allele_1_1 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Allele_2</boldlabel><input id=allele_1_2 name=allele_1_2 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Run date</boldlabel><input id=run_date1 name=run_date1 size=10 disabled=true>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
    <LEGEND><b>Edit Genotype, call 2</b></LEGEND>
      <boldlabel>Allele_1</boldlabel><input id=allele_2_1 name=allele_2_1 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Allele_2</boldlabel><input id=allele_2_2 name=allele_2_2 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Run date</boldlabel><input id=run_date2 name=run_date2 size=10 disabled=true>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
    <LEGEND><b>Edit Genotype, call 3</b></LEGEND>
      <boldlabel>Allele_1</boldlabel><input id=allele_3_1 name=allele_3_1 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Allele_2</boldlabel><input id=allele_3_2 name=allele_3_2 size=5 >
      <boldlabel>Run date</boldlabel><input id=run_date3 name=run_date3 size=10 disabled=true>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Finally, here's my script:

```
 function clear_fetch() {    

    $('#fetch_results:input', $(this)).each(function(index) {
      this.value = "";
    })

  }
```

However, nothing happens...so, I must not have the selector correct. Does anybody see what I've done wrong?

Comment: this works for me: $(".fetch_results:input").val("");

Answer (score 95, accepted):

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/simple/BdQvp/

**You can do it like so:**

I have added two buttons in the Fiddle to illustrate how you can insert or clear values in those input fields through buttons. You just capture the *onClick* event and call the function.

```
//Fires when the Document Loads, clears all input fields
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('');    
});

//Custom Functions that you can call
function resetAllValues() {
  $('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('');
}

function addSomeValues() {
  $('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('Lala.');
}
```

**Update:**

Check out [this great answer below by Beena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543104/how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-a-specific-div-with-jquery/10892768#10892768) as well for a more universal approach.

Comment: How about SELECT options?

Comment: Feel free to add suggestions if you have any, this isn't a complete answer of all ways to do it.

Comment: Targeting below will clear ALL types

$('.fetch_results').find(':input').val('');

Answer (score 90):

This function is used to clear all the elements in the form including radio button, check-box, select, multiple select, password, text, textarea, file.

```
function clear_form_elements(class_name) {
  jQuery("."+class_name).find(':input').each(function() {
    switch(this.type) {
        case 'password':
        case 'text':
        case 'textarea':
        case 'file':
        case 'select-one':
        case 'select-multiple':
        case 'date':
        case 'number':
        case 'tel':
        case 'email':
            jQuery(this).val('');
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'radio':
            this.checked = false;
            break;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: changed `jQuery` to `$`, but this works perfectly for all the types listed!

Comment: You cannot set the value to file inputs, even to blanck it.

Comment: need add reset for select option selected.

Comment: Working perfectly, for 'select2' type element I made bit change in it like  - `case 'select-one':
    case 'select-multiple':
     $(this).val('').change(); // via change(), working for select2 also 
     break;`

Answer (score 10):

Change this:

```
 <div class=fetch_results>
```

To this:

```
 <div id="fetch_results">
```

Then the following should work:

```
$("#fetch_results input").each(function() {
      this.value = "";
  })​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NVqeR/

Comment: Upvoted, nice and simple. Change `input` to `:input` and it grabs textareas etc too.

Comment: @mikethirteen note that this answer is bit old and only addresses why OP's code didn't work. If you are just looking to clear all fields, `$("#fetch_results input").val("");` does the job and is much more succinct.

Answer (score 6):

inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892768/2087666 but I use the selector instead of a class and prefer if over switch:

```
function clearAllInputs(selector) {
  $(selector).find(':input').each(function() {
    if(this.type == 'submit'){
          //do nothing
      }
      else if(this.type == 'checkbox' || this.type == 'radio') {
        this.checked = false;
      }
      else if(this.type == 'file'){
        var control = $(this);
        control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
      }else{
        $(this).val('');
      }
   });
}
```

this should take care of almost all input inside any selector.

Comment: else{
              $(this).val('');
           }
is for default case where you can clear them with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Couple issues that I see.  `fetch_results` is a class, not an Id and the each function doesn't look right.

```
$('.fetch_results:input').each(function() {
      $(this).val('');
});
```

Just be sure to remember that if you end up with radios or check buttons, you will have to clear the checked attribute, not the value.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to delete all inputs within a div & using the colon in front of the input when targeting gets most everything.

```
$('#divId').find(':input').val('');
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This should be the correct answer. Thanks @tanner_gram

Comment: Is that working for all inputs @Tanner_Gram? I guess you should loop within the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Beena's answer in ES6 Sans the JQuery dependency.. Thank's Beena!

```
let resetFormObject = (elementID)=> {
        document.getElementById(elementID).getElementsByTagName('input').forEach((input)=>{
            switch(input.type) {
                case 'password':
                case 'text':
                case 'textarea':
                case 'file':
                case 'select-one':
                case 'select-multiple':
                case 'date':
                case 'number':
                case 'tel':
                case 'email':
                    input.value = '';
                    break;
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    input.checked = false;
                    break;
            }
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to stay with a class level selector then you could do something like this (using the same jfiddle from Mahn)

```
$("div.fetch_results input:text").each(function() {
  this.value = "testing";
})​
```

This will select only the text input boxes within the div with a fetch_results class.

As with any jQuery this is just one way to do it.  Ask 10 jQuery people this question and you will get 12 answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('.fetch_results input'), function(idx, input){
  $(input).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some who wants to reset the form can also use `type="reset"` inside any form.

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
Pin: <input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="4"><br>
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one liner that worked for me

```
$('input','.container_class_name').val(null).trigger('change');
```

`'input'` being the elements you want to clear within the container, &
`'container_class_name'` being the container class or id name.

This works for all input's regardless of type (checkbox, radio, text), since the pointer is looking at the `<input>` element itself.