# How can I display a Reset button on a form ony after the form has submitted?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, ispostback

After a form submits, it reverts to its original state (for the most part), and we want to have a "`Reset`" button that allows the user to start the page "`afresh`". I was hoping I could define and configure the `HtmlButton` in code:

```
HtmlButton btnStartNewDirPay = null;
. . .
private void CreateAndConfigureButtonStartNewDirectPayment()
{
    btnStartNewDirPay = new HtmlButton();
    btnStartNewDirPay.Attributes["type"] = "reset";
    btnStartNewDirPay.InnerHtml = "Start new Direct Pay";
    btnStartNewDirPay.ID = "btnStartNewDirPay";
}
```

...and then instantiate it only on `postback` (after the `form` has submitted) like so:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) 
{
    if (null == btnStartNewDirPay)
    {
        CreateAndConfigureButtonStartNewDirectPayment();
    }
    this.Controls.Add(btnStartNewDirPay); //this causes problems
}
```

But the last line (where the button is added to the page's (this's) Controls), it fails with:

> System.Web.HttpException was unhandled by user code   Message=Failed
>   to load viewstate.  The control tree into which viewstate is being
>   loaded must match the control tree that was used to save viewstate
>   during the previous request.  For example, when adding controls
>   dynamically, the controls added during a post-back must match the type
>   and position of the controls added during the initial request.
>   Source=System.Web   ErrorCode=-2147467259   StackTrace:
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(Object savedState)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
>          at DirectPaymentSectionsWebPart.DPSVisualWebPart.DPSVisualWebPartUserControl.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>          at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

I also tried creating/configuring the HtmlButton at the beginning (when IsPostBack was false), by adding the control to "this" from the git-go, like this:

```
private void CreateAndConfigureButtonStartNewDirectPayment()
{
    btnStartNewDirPay = new HtmlButton();
    btnStartNewDirPay.Attributes["type"] = "reset";
    btnStartNewDirPay.InnerHtml = "Start new Direct Pay";
    btnStartNewDirPay.ID = "btnStartNewDirPay";
    this.Controls.Add(btnStartNewDirPay);
}
```

...and then hiding it via jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    . . .
        $('[id$=btnStartNewDirPay]').hide();
});
```

...but that also failed on the same line ("*this.Controls.Add(btnStartNewDirPay);*") in "CreateAndConfigureButtonStartNewDirectPayment()" with the same err msg as above, once IsPostBack is true.

So it won't allow me to instantiate and hide the HtmlButton at the beginning, and later show it when IsPostBack is true; Nor will it allow me to defer instantiation to when IsPostBack is true, it seems. Surely it's possible to have an element that displays after a postback but not prior to that...but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new button is over kill here.

Just have the button on the view like so and make it visible=false.

```
<asp:Button id="btnStartNewDirPay" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Reset" runat="server" Visible="False" />
```

Set its ClientIDMode to static so the id is easier to get via jQuery.

Then on post back at the end of the saving set the visible to true.

```
if(IsPostBack)
{
    ....
    btnStartNewDirPay.Visible = true;
}
```

On the front end then have a click listener

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnStartNewDirPay").click(function(){
        //Reset inputs to default values.
    })
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "type="reset"" in there, too?

Comment: Well my implementation would not use the reset button type. I would just use jquery/js to empty the fields which you could easily do really. A simple `$('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");`. This way you have a little more control on what you are resetting.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I would need this to work on the entire page, which has no forms. Is there jQuery "shorthand" for "everything" (the page itself does not have an ID that can be referenced, I don't think).

Comment: You could add a class to each input and select on it `$(".someClass").val("")`. If you don't want to add a class you could use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10892768/4488112.

Comment: I realized that I also need to uncheck checkboxes and radiobuttons, so I may be stuck writing code to explicitly do all that.