# How to Clear all TextBox value in page with MasterPage using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page in asp.net with a MasterPage. I must clear all textbox value inside a div using jquery.
i know i can clear them with their id like this :

```
$('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val('');
```

but i want clear them at once without their id;
could anyone help me , please?

**Update :**

```
    $(".custom-menu li").click(function () {
            case "AddNode":

                $('#<%=txtName.ClientID %>').val(''); // worked
                $('#<%=txtLastName.ClientID %>').val(''); //worked
                $('#<%=txtDesc.ClientID %>').val(''); //worked

                //$('.treeView input[type=text]').val(''); //don't work
                //$('input[type="text"]', $('#chartBox')).val(''); //don't work



                //$('#chartBox input').val(''); ////don't work

                $("#chartBox").find('input:text, input:password, input:file').val(''); //don't work
                break;
        }
        $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    });
```

Comment: `$('input:text').val('');`?

Comment: Put a common class on all the elements you want to clear and use your above code: `$('.myCommonClass').val('');`

Comment: i have tested all of them ,doesn't work with masterpage

Comment: Can you share how you have utilized it, In which of your code you are trying to perform this clear action for all textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all the textbox present inside the div like this:-

```
$('input[type="text"]',$('#divId')).val('');
```

Notice the second parameter is `context` withing which you wanna find all the controls. Since you wanna find all the textbox inside div, I am passing the id of div as second parameter.

Comment: @Farzaneh - Have you even tried it? Master page is also rendered a HTML it is not different. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$('#divId input').val('');
```

OR

```
$("#divID").find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

OR

assign common css class to all textbox and try below code.

```
$('.yourcssclass').val('');
```

Comment: you can try all above methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all of the input fields with type="text" use this:

```
$("input[type='text'].foreach(
    function(){
        $(this).val('');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it like so:**

I have added two buttons in the Fiddle to illustrate how you can insert or clear values in those input fields through buttons. You just capture the onClick event and call the function.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/simple/BdQvp/)

```
//Fires when the Document Loads, clears all input fields
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('');    
});

//Custom Functions that you can call
function resetAllValues() {
$('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('');
}

function addSomeValues() {
$('.fetch_results').find('input:text').val('Lala.');
}
```

Check out [this great answer below by Beena](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543104/how-to-clear-all-input-fields-in-a-specific-div-with-jquery/10892768#10892768) as well for a more universal approach.

Comment: What do you mean?? Kindly tell me your file structure

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divid").find('input:text, input:password, input:file').val('');
```

Comment: It is executing clientside.From which event you r trying to clear textbox? and from which control event? Is that control belongs to master page?

Comment: If your div is runat server then you should take clientid.otherwise not required.Please put your code fully,otherwise it difficult to understand.